Show a message in the header when a tablix's detail section overflows to the next page
I'm creating an SSRS report to create a dynamic form. This form contains a dynamic set of instructions for the users that consume this form. Each line for this form is placed into a tablix and due to how dynamic the contents, including the instructions, can be it sometimes overflows to the next page or even further, spanning multiple pages for once instance. When the data spans multiple pages I am trying to show a message to the user to inform them that the content on the top of this page is overflowed from the previous page.
We were able to do this in Crystal Reports before by setting a variable as the data was being processed, but due to how SSRS renders the reports this doesn't seem to work.
Here's what I have tried so far, with no luck:

Added custom code to SSRS report that is called for each row in SSRS to store the current row or title of instructions, then at the end of the row, I would unset this variable to make it not show up on the page.
a.) This is the same way that it was done in the Crystal Report, but, since SSRS renders reports differently, the body would continue processing prior to rendering the header, which caused the variable to update with the next full row on the page, rather than processing the previous row's information first.

Repeated a header from the Tablix on each page
a.) The repeated header only showed up below the overflowed text, not on top of it, which is the behavior I need to happen so users can be aware of what they are viewing.



This doesn't sound like a task for SSRS, if I am honest.
